# how to provide authentication functions to asterisk？(asterisk+radiusclient-ng)

Tags: authentication, asterisk

I searched and got much time to provide authentication function for my asterisk server.I want to authenticate and authorize for SiP user, it is my project.But i did not finish it.
  My asterisk version is 1.8.8.1  CentOS release 6.2.I don't know to fix this problem.
  who can help me!! Thanks you in advance!! :confused

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the asterisk cli: `core show application Authenticate`